# Can I search for a Unicode combining character in Vim?

Tags: search, regular-expression, unicode

I have a file with the character `ã` (lowercase a + combining tilde).  `Encoding` and `fileencoding` are both `utf-8`.  `ga` shows

```
<a> 97, hex 61, octal 141 <~> 771, Hex 0303, Octal 1403
```

(but with the actual combining tilde in the `<>`) and `g8` shows

```
61 + cc 83
```

Searching with `/a\%u0303` works fine.

Searching for just `\%u0303` gives E486 Pattern not Found.

Can I search for just the combining character without also searching for the base character?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Type in normal mode `/<ctr-v>u0303`

`/` - start search

`<Ctr-v>u` - init utf-8 code input

`0303` - hex code combine character.

`:he unicode`

Also `:he mbyte-combining` and `:he utf-8-char-arg` the last one covered case with commands like `f`, `F` and so on.

Comment: Interestingly, this only works if the character is combined with something.
If a file or line begins with the 0303 character, it won't be found by this method.