# What's the difference between "qp and <c-r><c-r>q when you store a macro?

Tags: macro, register

I used to store macros in insert mode as `<c-r><c-r>q`, but that fails if the macro contains a special character such as `<C-Right>`

If I record a macro as

```
qq<C-Right>q.
```

the result of `<c-r><c-r>q` in insert mode is :

```
<80>ýV
```

the result of `"qp` in normal mode is :

```
<80><fd>V
```

If I copy the result back to a new register `"ay$` , only the `"qp` approach works. The first character in the newly copied register of the `<c-r><c-r>q` approach is `<c2>`, I have no idea what `<c2>` is, it's echo result is 0.

So my question is what's the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what's the difference between these two methods?

[`p`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#p) inserts the content of a register
as it is, regardless of the encoding, but [`CTRL-R CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R)
encodes sequences of bytes before inserting them.

#### Explanation

Special key combinations, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, are translated
into terminal keycodes like `^[[1;5C`, then into vim keycodes like `<C-Right>`,
and finally into a sequence of bytes starting with `0x80` like `<80><fd>V` (`<80>` is `0x80`)

<sup>[[1]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-the-difference-between-mapped-key-sequences-and-key-codes-timeoutl/10284#10284)
[[2]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14446/6698)
[[3]](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getchar%28%29)
[[4]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6088/using-c-causes-80%c3%bcd-to-flash-in-the-showcmd-area#comment18157_6088)
[[5]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6088/using-c-causes-80%c3%bcd-to-flash-in-the-showcmd-area#comment18160_6088)</sup>.
This is a special case where the vim keycode is different than the terminal keycode
<sup>[[6]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20347/6698)</sup>.

After assigning the register `q` like this:

```
let @q="\<C-Right>"
```

the sequence of bytes is what's actually saved:

```
:registers q
Type Name Content
  c  "q   <80><fd>V
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I went to insert mode and put this sequence by hand as [Unicode code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)
<sup>[[7]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/555/6698)
[[8]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3558/6698)
[[9]](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V_digit)</sup> (`V` is `0x56` here)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> for [`<80>`](https://codepoints.net/U+0080)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> for [`<fd>`](https://codepoints.net/U+00fd)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> for [`V`](https://codepoints.net/U+0056)

This is what I would get:

```
<80>ýV
```

which is the same result as the one I would get if I pressed

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> in insert mode.

> I have no idea what `<c2>` is

If the cursor is moved on the opening angle bracket `<` in the previous output:

```
<80>ýV
```

and then press [`g8`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#g8) in normal mode, this is the output I'd get <sup>[[10]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/560/6698)[[11]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21471/6698)</sup>:

```
c2 80
```

These are the hexadecimal numbers for the two-byte UTF-8 character under the cursor; so the `<c2>` is the first byte of the two.

As a final note, what follows is the output of `"qp` in normal mode:

```
<80><fd>V
```

If I again move the cursor on the first `<` and press `g8` the output would be different:

```
80
```

because that's not a UTF-8 character but just a binary one.

Thanks to all the Vi and Vim community (including you) who made this answer possible.  I hope this answer is useful.

Comment: Very well explained! Great answer.

Comment: Thank you @dedowsdi

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to insert the content of a registers. I'm going to briefly discuss some that are inserted when in `:h Insert-mode`:

- `:h i_CTRL-R` : Insert the content of a register. Unlike, `:h p` or `:h P` i.e. `"qp`, how the texts are inserted will be affected by options like `:h textwidth`, `:h formatoptions` or `:h autoindent`.
- `:h i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R` : Works like using a single CTRL-R, but the text is inserted literally, not as if typed. So, if you record hitting a backspace, e.g. `type^Hing`, would insert `typing` when inserted with single CTRL-R but will insert `type^Hing` when inserted with double CTRL-R. (`^H` is CTRL-H, used for `<BS>` in terminal emulators, i.e. they emit same code `<U+0008`). Still is affected by auto-indent options.
- `:h i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O` : Insert text literally and isn't affected by auto-indent.
- `:h i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P` : Insert the contents of a register literally and fix the indent.

Now, when you pressed `<Ctrl-Right>` after starting the recording, your terminal emulator emits some keycodes. I don't exactly know what they might be and most probably they even differ from computer to computer. So, it's a wildcard why the characters `<80>` `<fd>` (both hexadecimal values) and most confusingly why `V` is there! I have no answer to these. The only thing I have advanced on your observations is that both `ý` and `<fd>` are basically same character, i.e. they both have same HEX values which is `00FD`. Double `CTRL-R`, i.e. `i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R`, inserts literal characters. That's why it inserted the literal value of `<fd>` and not the HEX value which is saved in its `:h digraph`.

So, to wrap it up:

- Check out the documentations to know about various ways to insert content of a register and differences among them.
- `<fd>` and `ý` are same character, former is HEX value and latter is ASCII value.
- No idea why there is a literal `V` in the `<C-Right>` `:h key-codes` recording
- No idea how to make sense of these nonsensical key-codes. And I suppose, in order to not have to think about these key-codes, vim provides us sensible `:h key-codes` for mappings and such.

**Edit**

You can't use the literal string that you got when you inserted it with `:h i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R` to use as a recording. Because the literal string that the extended ASCII key-code spews out is not within one of `:h key-codes`. For example, if you want to insert `<C-Right>` into a register and use it, you need to do it in the following way:

```
:let @q = "\<C-Right>"
```

The backslash and double-quote is necessary to evaluate to special characters, see `:h string` and `:h literal-string`.

In other words, the weird character that the HEX value of `<fd>` evaluates to in extended ASCII chart is not going to be converted to special characters or key-codes in `:h key-codes`.

Comment: I know `<c-r><c-r>` insert literal content, i should've mensioned it. The question is why can't you copy literal macro text back to reqister, and use it as a macro, while the normal "qp approach works, `help p` only says "put the text ..... ".

Comment: I edited my answer. Check if it helps

Comment: I'm not sure, i just tried `let @q = "<c-v><C-Right>"` , then @q, vim works,  neovim failed. I also tried `let @q = "\<C-Right>"`, both vim and neovim works.

Comment: <c-v><C-Right>  is "<C-Right>" in neovim, "^[[1;5C" in vim.

Comment: I'm as clueless as you are. I know that my terminal bash uses `^[[1;5C` as right arrow, but I don't know how neovim and vim handles it. `^[[1;5C` is `\<Esc>1;5C` as non-literal special `:h string`

Comment: <80><fd> is also not in keycodes,  but it can be copied back to register to make a valid macro.

Comment: Yes, you can because it is keycode, not a special key-code. The confusions are arising due to my misuse of terms. The special characters provided in `:h key-codes` can be used as literal or non-literal strings, e.g. `'<C-Right>'` or `"\<C-Right>"`. Now, when you're using `<80><fd>` directly, it is being used as you expect. But if you copy `<80>ý`, it's not gonna work because `ý` would not work as `<fd>`, it will be another usual ASCII character. So, basically, you can use direct codes like `<fd>` but not their ASCII values like `ý` in a macro. And you can use special keys like `<C-Right>`