# What is the difference between <C-V>x and \x?

Tags: string-manipulation, control-character

Run the following commands, where `<80>` is a literal byte entered by typing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>:

```
let literal = "<80>"
let quoted  = "\x80"
```

- `echo(literal)` and `echo(quoted)` will now both output `<80>`, but,
- `len(literal)` returns `2` instead of the expected `1`, and
- `:echo literal[0]` outputs `<c2>`. The expected `<80>` byte appears to be in `literal[1]`.

Where does this extra byte prefix come from? Why doesn't entering bytes with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> result in the same sequences of bytes as adding them with a `\x` special character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where does this extra byte prefix come from?

`literal` holds an UTF-8 encoded string. `<80>` is encoded in two bytes according to UTF-8 standard specification.

Here bold bits are used by UTF-8 decoder only. The remaining 11 bits are the value of `0x80` prefixed with 3 zero bits.

> **1 1 0** 0 0 0 1 0 | **1 0** 0 0 0 0 0 0

- **1 1 0** --- the next char is encoded in two bytes (octets)
- **1 0** --- the "continuation" octet

On the other hand, `"\x80"` is a "byte" as defined per `:h expr-quote`, so it never gets encoded in UTF-8. A quote from the help page:

> Note that "\xff" is stored as the byte 255, which may be invalid in some
>   encodings.  Use "\u00ff" to store character 255 according to the current value
>   of 'encoding'.

Comment: Okay.  I think my mistake was in thinking that `<80>` was a byte too, but if I understand you correctly, it's actually unicode character 0080. `:echo "\u0080" == "<80>" reports 1, so that checks out. Thanks!