# How can I search for Unicode characters by hex code in very magic regexes in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, unicode, encoding, multibyte

I am working on [UTF-8 support for my editorconfig-core vimscript plugin](https://github.com/cxw42/editorconfig-core-vimscript/issues/2).  I have hit a strange snag.

This is in official GVim 7.4 Win32.  I would like to get this working on 7.4, rather than updating to 8.0, so the plugin can be more widely usable.  It has `+iconv/dyn`, `+multi_byte_ime/dyn`, and `+multi_lang`.  (Strangely, it does not show `+multi_byte`, but UTF-8 editing works fine.)

**Edit** I can also reproduce on Cygwin Vim running in mintty 3.0.0.  That is Vim 8.0 with `+iconv`, `+multi_byte`, and `+multi_lang`.  Vim encoding is utf-8; `$LANG` is `en_US.UTF-8`.

#### Steps to reproduce

- Open a new buffer
- `set encoding=utf8<CR>`
- Paste in `中文` (U+4e2d, UTF8 e4 b8 ad; U+6587, UTF8 e6 96 87)
- Search: `/\%u4e2d<CR>`.  The search should land on the first character.
- Search **using very-magic regexes**: `/\v\%u4e2d<CR>`.

  - When I do this, I get `E486: Pattern not found: \v\%u4e2d`.

Per [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3558/1430), I also tried searching by unicode character entry: `/\v<Ctrl+V>u4e2d<CR>`.  This does return a match.

Why does `\%u4e2d` not match in very-magic mode, when it does match in magic mode?  I also tried nomagic and very-nomagic, and it matches in both of those as well.

#### Context (aka XY problem)

I am trying to build a regex that will match against a filename.  In my particular test case, I have:

```
regex:    \v\/editorconfig\-core\-vimscript\/localtests\/glob\/\中\文\.txt\_$
test:     /editorconfig-core-vimscript/localtests/glob/中文.txt
```

Now

```
:echo match('/editorconfig-core-vimscript/localtests/glob/中文.txt', '\v\/editorconfig\-core\-vimscript\/localtests\/glob\/\中\文\.txt\_$')
```

returns `-1` (no match), even though the similar-seeming `match('a','\v\a')` returns `0` (match found).

My thought was that I could convert any character >127 into its corresponding `\%uNNNN` using `char2nr()` and `printf()`.  However, I ran into the problem above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the "how" answer is very simple:  In very-magic mode, `%` is already magical.  Therefore, instead of `\%u4e2d`, `%u4e2d` (no backslash) works fine!  In full, that's

```
/\v%u4e2d<CR>
```

Comment: Why did you use `\中`and not `中`? It seems to work as expected without that backslash in recent Vim versions, anyway?

Comment: @MartinTournoij It was a side-effect of what I was doing - I was escaping characters for inclusion in a very-magic regex by `s/\v([^a-zA-Z0-9_])/\\\1/g`, which backslashed everything above char 127.  `中` just happened to be the test character that exhibited the problem.

Comment: Right, so removing those backslashes fixes your problem? (they're in the regex in the question, too)

Comment: @MartinTournoij Yes, for this and my other recent question, removing backslashes was the answer.  This is my first foray into changing magic level, and I am learning as I go.